# Formatting columns of multidimensional arrays into 1D arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy, slice, numpy-ndarray

I want to access right side of the 2D array. I would like to turn the second column into a 1D array `4883,4967,4968...` . I tried doing `list_[len(list_),1]` however that doesn't work. How would I be able to do that.

```
list_ = np.array([[   1 4883]
 [   0 4967]
 [   1 4968]
 [   0 4969]
 [   1 4969]
 [   0 4970]
 [   1 4971]
 [   0 4971]
 [   1 4972]
 [   0 4973]
 [   1 4973]
 [   0 4974]
 [   1 4975]
 [   0 4975]
 [   1 4976]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply index as follows -

```
l[:,1]
```